# Responsive grid with different-sized image thumbnails and aligned text above

Tags: html, css, markdown

I am trying to fix following css/markdown/HTML code so that it is properly responsive on mobile devices and smaller web browsers:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
.thumbnail1 {
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

<style>
.thumbnail2 {
    background-color: black;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline-block; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

### Book

<p style="font-size: 11.5pt; width: 47%; text-align: left; margin-right: 3%;">"<a href="Book link">Book Title</a>." Under contract with <b><i>Publisher</i></b> (w/ coauthor 1 & coauthor).<br><a href="link for Book image"><img src="image source file for Book" class="thumbnail1" style="max-width: 100%;"></a></p> 

### Peer-Reviewed Articles 

<p style="float: left; font-size: 11.5pt; text-align: left; width: 47%; margin-right: 3%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">"<a href="article 1 link">Article 1 Title</a>."<b><i> Article 1 Journal</i></b> (w/ coauthor).<a href="Article 1 link"><img src="image source file for Article 1" class="thumbnail1" style="max-width: 100%;"></a></p>
<p style="float: right; font-size: 11.5pt; text-align: left; width: 47%; margin-left: 3%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">"<a href="Article 2 link">Article 2 Title</a>."<b><i> Article 2 Journal</i></b> (w/ coauthors).<a href="link for Article 2 image"><img src="image source file for Article 2" class="thumbnail2" style="max-width: 100%;"></a></p> 
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

It works perfectly on the computer, producing the following perfectly lined up images and text:
[image]

However, on a mobile device or with a half-sized internet window, everything gets squished and does not line-up well along the lines of:
[image]

How can I change code so that the grid just turns into one tile on a mobile device or a narrower web browser--i.e., like this?
[image]

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880534/how-to-make-3-column-css-grid-change-into-1-column-on-mobiles-with-media-query

Comment: @dalelandry Thanks, but I am not quite sure how to adapt my code based on that post, which uses media and other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself using these two pages: [page 1](https://travishorn.com/responsive-grid-in-2-minutes-with-css-grid-layout-4842a41420fe) and [page 2](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-modern-css-to-build-a-responsive-image-grid/). Here is the revised CSS:

```
.thumbnail1 {
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.thumbnail2 {
    background-color: black;
    height: 228px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}
```

And here is the revised code:

```
<h2>Book</h2>

<div class="cards">
<div class="card">
<p style="font-size: 11.5pt; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">"<a href="Book link">Book Title</a>." Under contract with <b><i>Publisher</i></b> (w/ coauthor 1 & coauthor).<br><a href="link for Book image"><img src="image source file for Book" class="thumbnail1" style="width: 90%;"></a></p></div>
</div>

<h2>Published Academic Articles</h2>
<div class="cards">
<div class="card">
<p style="font-size: 11.5pt; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">"<a href="article 1 link">Article 1 Title</a>."<b><i> Article 1 Journal</i></b> (w/ coauthor).<a href="Article 1 link"><img src="image source file for Article 1" class="thumbnail1" style="width: 90%;"></a></p></div>
<div class="card">
<p style="font-size: 11.5pt; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">"<a href="Article 2 link">Article 2 Title</a>."<b><i> Article 2 Journal</i></b> (w/ coauthors).<a href="link for Article 2 image"><img src="image source file for Article 2" class="thumbnail2" style="width: 90%;"></a></p></div>
</div>
```

I added `style: "width: 90%;` for the `img` because `text-align: left` is not perfectly justified. This way, the image does not appear outside the unjustified text.